# Increment number in bash variable string

Tags: bash, awk, arithmetic

```
VERSION="4.0beta12"
NEXT_VERSION=?????
```

Writing an automatic release script, I have the current version in a variable $VERSION, and I would like to calculate the next version as $NEXT_VERSION.

Rule: Increment the integer at the end of the string.
4.0beta12 → 4.0beta13
4.2alpha9 → 4.2alpha10

I have tried with sed/awk/eval but can't make it work. Ideas? Any tool is fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need for anything but Bash:

```
for version in 12.4alpha9 12.4alpha12 12.4alpha-2; do
    echo -n "$version => ";
    [[ "$version" =~ (.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)$ ]] && version="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$((${BASH_REMATCH[2]} + 1))";
    echo "$version";
done
```

The only line really relevant to you, is the one with the regex check `[[`: it remembers everything leading up to the final number, reuses that and appends the next number.

Comment: Inside arithmetic evaluation no need to use `${}` around the variable: `$((BASH_REMATCH[2] + 1))` is enough.

Comment: Works very well, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you always have some reasonable well-formedness rules (always a non-digit in the version, version always ends in digits), this, however klunky, might be a start:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
1 {
    pfx = gensub(/^(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)$/, "\\1", "")
    patchlevel = gensub(/^(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)$/, "\\2", "")

    new_pl = (1*patchlevel)+1
    printf "%s%s\n", pfx, new_pl
}
```

Test:

```
[0 1066] ~/temp % echo "12.4alpha9" | gawk -f incvers.awk
12.4alpha10
[0 1067] ~/temp % echo "12.4alpha12" | gawk -f incvers.awk
12.4alpha13
[0 1068] ~/temp % echo "12.4alpha-2" | gawk -f incvers.awk
12.4alpha-3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try having

```
MAJOR=4
MINOR=0
STATE="beta"
POINT=9
VERSION=$MAJOR.$MINOR$STATE$POINT
NEXT_VERSION=$MAJOR.$MINOR$STATE$((POINT +1 ))

echo "Next version is $NEXT_VERSION"
# other release stuff here
```

Do want this to be a self-rewriting script? I'd suggest something like

```
tempfile=$( tempfile -d . )
sed -re "s/POINT=[0-9]+/POINT=$(( ++POINT ))/" $0 > $tempfile
chmod +x $tempfile
mv $tempfile $0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a portable shell snippet that adds 1 to the number at the end of `$current_version`.

```
n=${current_version##*[!0-9]}; p=${current_version%%$n}
next_version=$p$((n+1))
```

Just because it's simple (well, fairly simple) doesn't mean it's a good idea. Like [Andrew](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23174/increment-number-in-bash-variable-string/23177#23177), I recommend breaking down your variable definitions into components.